# Use Special Character in iOS Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Hi I have Used Question Mark (?) in the Product Name of iOS Application , which cause my whole application to display special characters instead of text [image]on different screens.

Is there any solution to add ? to application name and it work smoothly as before.

Answer (score 1):

If the product name causes trouble, change it. The user will never see it, so what do you care? The product name is arbitrary. It is *not* the application name! What the user sees is the *display* name, which is completely different.

Comment: On Xcode8 We have Product Name which is actually application name/ display name

Comment: No it isn't. Try to understand that you are the one asking. That means you don't know. Listen to the answer. The product name is just the _ipa_ file name. It is not the app name that the user sees.

Comment: ok got It, solution is to add Bundle Display Name in Info.plist.